# C++ stack leak with std::thread class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-leaks

I have what appears to be a stack leak directly attributable to using std::thread. To boil it down to the simplest example, I used the example code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach but modified it to loop and call the thread creating function multiple times and removed extraneous code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void independentThread() 
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
}

void threadCaller() 
{
    std::thread t(independentThread);
    t.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}

int main() 
{
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
       threadCaller();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(50));
}
```

Then I compiled the code with g++ 8.3:

```
 g++ -std=c++14 -pthread -g -fstack-check -fstack-protector-all -finstrument-functions thread_test.cpp -o t_test
```

Then I ran the code with valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --stacks=yes --time-unit=ms ./t_test
```

The output from valgrind is run through "ms_print" and then moved to excel to chart:
[Chart of stack and heap bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD5St.jpg)

Everything I see points to a memory leak caused by the thread. I've tried using join but even then there is still a leak and join won't work for my application. I'm running this on linux 4.14.77-70.59.amzn1.x86_64 with gcc version 8.3.0

Is there something I should be doing differently with the thread or is this "leak" just a misreported memory loss by valgrind?

Thanks

Comment: The program likely ends before all your threads stop running. Do you think that might be causing valgrind's output? Each thread has a live stack after all.

Comment: @Galik oops... my original test had shorter times so the sleep at the end of main would wait for exit. Just to be sure I re-ran with a longer sleep at the end and (separately) called "join" on each thread with nearly identical graphs to what was posted originally

Comment: @Cannonball *"Just to be sure I re-ran with a longer sleep at the end "* That's the problem with `detach`. You can never be sure. You have to pick an arbitrary time and hope that it was long enough. Any solution that would be sure would likely be easier to implement without `detach`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, if I have a print at the end of the "independentThread" function, they all print (and I presume the thread terminates) before main exits. Still, even if I join on every thread, I see the same growth in stack.

Comment: When I run this with your commands, (assuming I am reading valgrind right) I seem to get a maximum of about 10 stacks declining to 4 stacks by the end of the program. Which seems about right to me. Why clean up stacks when the program may need to re-use it for another thread? But your stacks seem to just keep going up...

Comment: How many cores do you have?

Comment: Have you tried to use `join`?

Comment: @Galik there are 2 cores, but my experience has shown that threads stay on the core that owns the process.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko, I have tried join. In the example code, I removed the detach call and place a join after the sleep. In that scenario there should never be more than 1 worker thread and it shows exactly the same stack growth.

Comment: With `--tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes` valgrind gives this code a clean bill of health: "All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible". Also gcc 8.3

Comment: @Cannonball It's not what I meant. You could make a vector of threads and join them after spawning them all

Comment: @Cannonball The thread isn't terminated after running the last statement. It just means it's about to begin ending. You can't be sure it's finished *that* process unless you `join`. If you have a working example using `join` I recommend you post that one instead.

Comment: Even if the `threadCaller` is modified to replace the call to `detach` with `join` the same stack growth appears to happen.
@MichaelNastenko - that is a possibility that I could manage a threadpool and re-use the same threads to halt the stack growth. I will test that on the example code to see what happens.

Comment: @Cannonball Usually, the best way to go is to make a fixed amount of threads (somewhere around N..2N, where N - CPU cores count) and supply them with work thru task queue. Stack growing could be a sign of some sort of OS optimization (probably, OS doesn't remove spawned threads, but store to an internal pool to reuse it later it the program will request one)